# Qna Maker Fetch Error from Azure Web App Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker

We have a code running in Azure Web App bot. If a client calls the bot , the bot checks the response from QnA maker and gives back the result. However when we tested , it was working fine with expected results. After an hour time it started giving the fetch error with respect to local issuer certificate.

```
Error :

[onTurnError]: FetchError: request to https://classa-xxx-qnaservice.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker/knowledgebases/c6912c27-913cd-2212-f823-f00a9128d0fa/generateanswer failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Code Snippet  :

```
const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(stepContext.context);

  // If an answer was received from QnA Maker, send the answer back to the user.
            if (qnaResults[0]) {
                await stepContext.context.sendActivity(qnaResults[0].answer);
                return this.endDialog();
```

Could anyone please help out .

Comment: Without having look on your code how could we assume? Include your code snippet on your question.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Added  the code snippet from where the call is being made to qna maker

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

Created a case with microsoft . The Troubleshooting was done in App service console. Where npm install was done again . Which resulted in vulnerabilities . **npm audit fix** was done post that and restarted the APP service again which sorted this problem.